# Unity --reset in 12.04 doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, unity

I was trying to disable the 'global menu' feature in Unity, and Unity began to malfunction. I was unable to move windows, the left menu bar had disappeared, and the top panel was also gone. I couldn't open a terminal as I couldn't move windows to get to my shortcut.

I used a virtual terminal(`tty2`), logged in, used `sudo`, and executed

`# unity --reset`

but it never finished.

I have pasted the output [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1049954/)

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Alt+T for other terminal-needing tight spots? Also, responding to your tag complaint, tags are meant for categorizing, not a description.

Comment: Running `unity` never finishes, until the Unity interface has terminated (which typically only happens on logout or if it's replaced with another instance). That part of what you're experiencing is normal, expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

After you run the command, you simply need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to unity.

If you want to get control to the terminal so you can run more commands, you can use:

```
nohup unity --replace&
```

where the ampersand makes it give control to the terminal, and the `nohup` makes the process immune to `SIGHUP` so you can `logoff` the tty without losing Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use root or sudo to use `unity --reset`. Call it with the user who wants to recover the default settings.

Note that this will reset all your unity setting to defaults. If you only want to restart unity use `unity --replace`

Comment: When I do unity --replace on Ubuntu 12.04 my computer crashes. This didn't happen with 11.10.

Comment: @ToDo You should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).